# How to use input tap command with the screen off

Tags: java, android, adb, root

I'm using adb commands with root access.
I can use these commands:

```
su
input tap 200 300
input swipe 100 200 200 200
```

But it doesn't work with the screen off.

How can I use these commands with the screen turned off?

Comment: uh, turn the screen on first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Turn off screen:

```
input keyevent 26
```

Turn on screen:

```
input keyevent 26
input swipe 100 200 200 200
```

It will press the power key.